# PHP/JQuery/AJAX form - server side validation only with in-line error styling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working on a form that submits via AJAX and is processed using PHP. I am looking to have server side validation with inline styling to correspond to whichever field(s) are are not valid. I have a setup that mostly works, however, it only every validates one field at a time.

i.e. if the user tries to submit the form but leaves 2 fields blank, only the first of those 2 is highlighted with the .error-field class I created. I'd rather that any and all fields that have errors be highlighted at once. I know I can do such a thing in jQuery by using a loop, but I'm wondering if that's something that is possible here using only server-side validation? I don't want to print an error message for each field as the form is very small and I have very little space to work with. I'd prefer to just highlight the field(s) that produce an error then display the "Please fill in the required fields" message.

The HTML for the form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="signupForm">
    <a class="sidebar">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left icon-arrow arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="closeBtn">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </a>

    <h2 class="text-center black">Sign up for our newsletter.</h2>

    <p class="errors-container light">Please fill in the required fields.</p>

    <div class="success">Thank you for signing up!</div>
    <div class="form-field-content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control FirstNameTxt" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="*First Name"
                   autofocus="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control LastNameTxt" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="*Last Name"
                   autofocus="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control EmailTxt" type="email" name="email" placeholder="*Email"
                   autofocus="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group submit-button">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-submit" type="button">SIGN-UP</button>
            <img src="/img/ajax-loader.gif" class="progress" alt="Submitting...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>                    
</form>
```

The jQuery + AJAX:

```
;(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var FirstName = $('.FirstNameTxt');
        var LastName = $('.LastNameTxt');
        var EmailAddress = $('.EmailTxt');
        var successMessage = $('.success');
        var error = $('.errors-container');
        var submitbtn = $('.button-submit');
        var SubmitProgress = $('img.progress');

        var formdata = {};
        submitbtn.click(function (e) {
            resetErrors();
            postForm();
        });

        function resetErrors() {
            $('.signupForm input').removeClass('error-field');
        }

        function postForm() {
            $.each($('.signupForm input'), function(i, v) {
                if (v.type !== 'submit') {
                    formdata[v.name] = v.value;
                }
            });

            submitbtn.hide();
            error.hide();
            SubmitProgress.show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                url: 'submission.php',
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function (response) {
                submitbtn.show();
                SubmitProgress.hide();
                console.log("here");
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                   var status = response[i].status;
                   var field = response[i].field;
                   if (status == "error") {
                     error.show();
                     $('input[name="' + field + '"]').addClass('error-field');
                   }
                    else if (status == "success") {
                        $('signupForm')[0].reset();
                        $('.form-field-content').hide();
                        successMessage.show();
                        $('.button-submit').html("Submitted");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The php code that handles the form:

```
$firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
$emailfield = $_POST['email'];

$return = [];

if($firstname == ""){
    $validatonStatus = "error";
    $errorField = "first_name";
}
else if($lastname == ""){
    $validatonStatus = "error";
    $errorField = "last_name";
}
else if($emailfield == "" || !filter_var($emailfield, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $validatonStatus = "error";
    $errorField = "email";
}
else {
    $validatonStatus = "success";
    $errorField = "";
   //send email notification

}
$return[] = array(
    "status" => $validatonStatus,
    "field" => $errorField,
);

echo (json_encode($return));
```

Comment: in your php code the $return array will always has 1 member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP code just returns an array with one element, not an element for each field. It needs to add a separate element to `$return` for each field.

It also shouldn't be using `elseif`, that prevents it from validating other fields when one is invalid.

```
if ($firstname == "") {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'first_name');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'first_name');
}

if ($lastname == "") {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'last_name');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'last_name');
}

if($emailfield == "" || !filter_var($emailfield, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $return[] = array('status' => 'error', 'field' => 'email');
} else {
    $return[] = array('status' => 'success', 'field' => 'email');
}
```